# Ищет изображение через папку css

Tags: css, браузер

Я указываю путь, чтобы через background поставить .png изображение. Браузер показывает ошибку, мол, не находит изображение. Я вижу, что он почему то ищет его через папку css. Как это исправить?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я все равно не понимаю, почему это не работает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Собственно, вот...[image: что ввести то]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Добавлять `../` в путях картинок в css

Comment: Да я добавлял... Я даже прописывал папку Project 1, чтобы уж наверняка он не делал путь через папку css, и все равно он делает путь через эту папку, хотя я ее в путь не прописывал.

Comment: а указать папку img вы не забываете?

Answer (score 0):

Осмелюсь предположить, что изображение лежит не в папке css. А в файле вы указываете путь до изображения в папке в которой находится сам файл css (в котором вы указываете путь до изображения)

Вам нужно указать путь следующим образом.

`..` - дает команду вернуться в предыдущий каталог

```
background: url('../img/icons/check.png');
```

Comment: Да, изображение в css не лежит. Оно лежит в в Project 1/img/icons/(само изображение). Я даже такой путь указываю, а в браузере он не находит это изображение, просто потому что он ищет так: /Project 1/css/img/icons/check.png. Почему так....

Comment: Попробуйте как я написал.

Comment: И покажите что получилось что написал браузер

Answer (score 0):

ВСЁ! Я без понятия почему так, но я не в scss, а в прикрепленном к scss файле css добавил ../ и в итоге это сработало.